# How to add badge to BottomNavigationBarItem in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

I have a BottomNavigationBar

```
BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            label: 'MyCart',
          ),
          .
          .
          .
          ])
```

I want add badge to MyCart icon, i saw Stack was used for BottomNavigationBar's icon like this:

```
new BottomNavigationBarItem(
        title: new Text('Home'),
        icon: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Icon(Icons.home),
            new Positioned(  // draw a red marble
              top: 0.0,
              right: 0.0,
              child: new Icon(Icons.brightness_1, size: 8.0, 
                color: Colors.redAccent),
            )
          ]
        ),
      )
```

but when I use it I get this error:

```
The values in a const list literal must be constants.
Try removing the keyword 'const' from the list literal.
```

Comment: What's unclear about the error? It tells you exactly how to fix it.

Comment: I overlooked it when you answered I checked again and saw that const is before items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `const` keyword before declaring the items inside `BottomNavigationBar`

Comment: also you dont need to add `new` everytime you create a new widget :)

Comment: Thanks for help bro , i overlooked :/

Answer (score 0):

The type of `MyCart` is `<Widget>` and  you set the `items` property on `BottomNavigationBar` to type `List<BottomNavigationBarItem>` set it to `List<Widget>`.Don't set it to `List<dynamic>` because all the children must be flutter widgets.If you do that and again  call `MyCart()` you will display to following Widget tree:

```
new BottomNavigationBarItem(
        title: new Text('Home'),
        icon: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Icon(Icons.home),
            new Positioned(  // draw a red marble
              top: 0.0,
              right: 0.0,
              child: new Icon(Icons.brightness_1, size: 8.0, 
                color: Colors.redAccent),
            )
          ]
        ),
      )
```

could be other solutions

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to use new/const, etc. see code below...

```
 bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'aaaaaa',
            icon: Stack(children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.home),
              Positioned(
                // draw a red marble
                top: 0.0,
                right: 0.0,
                child: Icon(Icons.brightness_1, size: 8.0, color: Colors.redAccent),
              )
            ]),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'dddddd',
            icon: Stack(children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.home),
              Positioned(
                // draw a red marble
                top: 0.0,
                right: 0.0,
                child: Icon(Icons.brightness_1, size: 8.0, color: Colors.redAccent),
              )
            ]),
          )
        ]),
```

Comment: Thanks for help bro, i overlooked :/